# Is it Possible to Send a File And or Folder Over Python's Socket Module?

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7

Essentially I'm making an application, the client checks if it has the needed files, if not it downloads them from the server. I'm wondering if I would be able to do that with Python's socket module, if so, how can I do such things?

Comment: you should be able to read the contents of the files and then send them over TCP to the client. You could probably have a length, hash that you can use to verify that you did not lose any bytes in the transfer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer:
There are probably easier ways to do it if you have control of both ends.  Using sockets directly is a somewhat low-level approach, and to get things working robustly, you would need to design a protocol to specify what file to request, have headers that specify length, etc, etc.

However, transferring files over a network is a problem that's been solved many times over, so there are several python modules to do it for you in much less code using a wide range of already developed protocols.

For example, with HTTP as the backend, the [requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module lets you do things like this:

```
r = requests.get('http://myserver/somefile.txt')
f = open('local_file_name.txt', w)
f.write(r.content)
f.close()
```

There are also python modules that would allow setting up a very simple HTTP server in very little code.

See here for one example (this actually doesn't require writing any code):
http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python

A simple test combining the two.  Assumes Linux, same basic principle applies on windows.  Open two consoles:

**Console 1:**

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir http_test_server
$ cd http_test_server
$ echo "Hello World" > test_file.txt
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

**Console 2:**

```
$ python
>>> import requests
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://localhost:8080/test_file.txt')
>>> r.content
'Hello World\n'
```

After running commands in Console 2, you should see output like this in console 1:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jan/2015 10:42:54] "GET /test_file.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: what would you suggest to set up the actual server? I'm extremely new to setting up server.